# Expected and order id to be passed con prestashop checkout

Tags: paypal, checkout

estoy trabajando con prestashop 1.7.2.2, con php 7.1.33 y con el módulo de prestashop checkout versión 2.18.0 y con multitiendas. El caso es que, en el front de algunas tiendas no funciona ningún método de pago (por ejemplo, paypal y tarjeta) y al hacer click en alguno de estos métodos, en consola, salta el siguiente error:
'Expected an order id to be passed', proveniente del archivo front.js del módulo. ¿Alguien sabe qué podría ser? Repito que funciona en algunas tiendas y en otras, no.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Sin un [example] poco te podremos ayudar. En estos casos lo mejor es acudir al creador del módulo y preguntarle a el, o buscar un foro específico de prestashop que esten más puestos.  Aquí tratamos mucho sobre lenguages de programación y muy poco sobre aplicativos que los esten usando a menos que nos pongan el código afectado y podamos reproducirlo en cierto modo. Léete tambien [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento de este sitio y como realizar buenas preguntas. Suerte!

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.